# Need to route non www url to www url and other routes should be as is

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know how to route example.com to www.example.com via .htaccess

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www. %{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

My requirement is example.com/something and so on should still be on example.com/something and not redirected to www.example.com/something. 
is it possible? Please help.

edit-
Let be more specific. I only want example.com to be routed to www.example.com. if example.com/abcd or example.com/wxyz it should not be rewritten. the contents of www.example.com is totally different from example.com. So I only want example.com to be routed to www.example.com and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another `RewriteCond` to exclude `/something` from this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You answer is more close to my requirement. The "something" part should be generic. if example.com/abcd or example.com/wxyz it should not be rewritten. How to do that?

Comment: Not working. example.com/abcd is redirecting to www.example.com

Comment: Also I need to exclude example.com/* (which is all the routes not just some specific routes)

Comment: Didn't understand what you mean by `Also I need to exclude example.com/*` What URI patterns should be redirected to `www` and what should not?

Comment: I only want example.com to be routed to www.example.com. All other requests to example.com should proceed as is.

Comment: Ah got it, that makes thing lot simpler :-) Check update now.

Answer (score 0):

Just Create `A` record that points your naked domain (example.com not www.example.com!) to IP address `174.129.25.170`

Now all requests going to example.com will be redirected to www.example.com and www.example.com itself is CNAME.

174.129.25.170 is the IP address of wwwizer service. What wwwizer does is that it detects if domain starts with 'www'. If not, it redirects request to URL with 'www' in it.

Part of the URL after slash("/") is preserved, meaning service will work for URLs having different paths, parameters, and anchors.

[more info about wwwizer](http://www.brainfuck.rs/2012-01-09-wwwizer-solve-your-naked-domain-problem-put-www-in-front-of-your-domain-name.html)

Comment: The answer by @anubhava is what I am looking for. But thank you anyway. :)